# how to only allow google apps auth from one domain with django

Tags: django, authentication, google-apps

I tried django-social-auth and googleappsauth but both allow me to 
authenticate from any domain.  Has anybody had luck setting this up 
with these, or any other packages?  If not, could someone point me in the right direction on how to implement from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: Hacked the django-social-auth Google back-end to filter by domain.  I'll see if the project wants to accept my changes as a setting.